# How to determine if today is the second thursday of each month in PHP?

Tags: php, date

How to determine if today is the second thursday of each month in PHP?

This is had what I had in mind, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (date('d', strtotime('second thursday')))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP does not read your mind :)

Comment: This should give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985637/third-thursday-of-the-month-in-php

Comment: `if (date('d') == date('d', strtotime('second thursday of this month'))) {` — That should work as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will echo the day of the second thursday of this month:

```
<?php
echo date('d', strtotime('second thursday of this month'));
// Will echo 10, which is correct for april 2014

echo date('d', strtotime('second thursday of next month'));
// Will echo 08, which is correct for may 2014

echo date('d', strtotime('second thursday of previous month'));
// Will echo 13, which is correct for march 2014
```

`If` statement for your question:

```
<?php
if (date('d') == date('d', strtotime('second thursday of this month'))) {
    echo 'Second thursday!';
} else {
    echo 'Not the second thursday';
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, didn't know strtotime accepted such parameters. Was thinking along the lines of checking if the day of the month is greater than 7, then checking if the day of the week is a thursday :P