# geting specific dates in the future with php

Tags: php, date

so my problem is rather simple but the solution keeps evading me. i am trying to get a list of future dates at a set interval that respects week nr in month and day nr in week. for example i need to make a list of dates of the 2nd mondays at 3 months apart.

i have a form where user specifies 2 dates and the interval.

so what i have is something like:

```
$start_date = "2015-01-07";
$end_date = "2016-01-07";
$period = "+1 month";
```

then, using this function from this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985637/third-thursday-of-the-month-in-php) i get what weeknr my start_date is: (ie: "first monday")

```
function literalDate($timestamp) {
    $timestamp = is_numeric($timestamp) ? $timestamp : strtotime($timestamp);
    $weekday = date('l', $timestamp);
    $month = date('M', $timestamp);

$ord = 1;

while(date('M', ($timestamp = strtotime('-1 week', $timestamp))) == $month) {
    $ord++;
}

$lit = array(null, 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth');

return $lit[$ord].' '.$weekday;
}
$day_number = literalDate($start_date);
$list=array();
```

then. i'm trying to do this

```
while(strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date))
{
  $list[]=$start_date;
  $start_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date $period"));
  $month = date('F', strtotime($start_date));
  $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day_number.' of '.$month)); //this always returns 1970-01-01
}

print_r($list);
```

as asked in comment my expected output is something like

```
array(
[0] => 2015-01-07
[1] => 2015-02-04
[2] => 2015-03-04
[3] => 2015-04-01
[4] => 2015-05-06
[5] => 2015-06-03
[6] => 2015-07-01
[7] => 2015-08-05
[8] => 2015-09-02
[9] => 2015-10-07
[10] => 2015-11-04
[11] => 2015-12-02
)
```

Comment: Show what your expected output is for the example you provided.

Comment: You're staggering your dates around between strings and integers like a drunk staggering down the road. Once you've strtotimed a string, **LEAVE** it as an integer, because invariably you're just going to be converting it back to an int again on the very next line of code.

Comment: for some reason my brain wasn't designed to comprehend the strtotime function(yes, i read the phpman about 1000 times). so therefore i don't know how to add the period to the $start_date whitout it being string. that's the whole reason for the abuse of conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, `DateInterval` should get you what you need:

```
$start    = new DateTime('2015-01-07');
$start->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('2016-01-07');
$end->modify('first day of this month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('first wednesday');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $d = $dt->format("d");
    if($d <= 7){
       echo $dt->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
    }
}
```

will display:

```
2015-01-07
2015-02-04
2015-03-04
2015-04-01
2015-05-06
2015-06-03
2015-07-01
2015-08-05
2015-09-02
2015-10-07
2015-11-04
2015-12-02
2016-01-06
```

Comment: that would be awesome of i could add "X months" to the object and move the a specific date like "second sunday" and just print that out.

Comment: yes, and notice that if statement, I had it less than 7 to only show the first monday, so you would have to change that

Comment: thanks mate, i already found how to increment the specified amount of months and leaned it up nicely, it was exactly what i needed! i owe you alot of beer for that, it was bugging me whole day! (ps: had to update php for this but worth it)

Comment: hahhaha, no problem. I always used this class (DateInterval) for any date ranges it is awesome

Comment: If you hadn't written your answer I would have written it exactly like this when i got home tonight.

Answer (score -1):

strtotime() which works in reference of today.

```
strtotime("+x days");
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

if you need something in relation to another date...

> date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yourdate) + 86400 * $days);

Comment: that dosen't work because i don't want to add x amount of time to the date. i want the date to be first, second, third, last, etc monday of a specific interval (1 month, 3 months, etc)  i have succeded in doing something similar but if i have a period of 1 month, and added 1 month, substracted 4 days and went to the next monday in the end it was a difference of 2, 3 weeks between start_date and end_date in 1 year. i need something more exact then that

Comment: I am giving you tools to do it, and not doing it for you. I am sorry that you feel as if the community should do it all for you.

Comment: no mate, i don't want you to do it for me, as you could have deduced from my code i already knew about strtotime. as explained in my comment, your answer did not help me one bit because i need a specific day of the week of the month. your answer did not provide that. and just so you know, i did not downvote your answer if that is what was bugging you.